# Liferay/Tomcat: Where do I put my own selection of spring-framework jars?

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

I want to program against the Spring *Portlet MVC framework* in liferay running under Tomcat.  For each portlet, I can put the spring framework -jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory of that portlet. I prefer to **not** do this. Seems redundant to me. 
Instead, can I put the spring framework jars somewhere else to make a  *single* selection of spring jars available to all my future portlets?

To my understanding, these locations are available, but which is "best"?

- ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/  (this is the dir of the liferay core)
- tomcat/lib/ext  (default location for all web-apps)
- docroot/WEB-INF/ext-lib/global (in [ext folder of of the liferay SDK](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/creating-an-ext-plugin))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tomcat version of Liferay I would recommend to put the external libraries in tomcat/lib/ext

Answer (score 1):

tomcat/lib/ext is the place to go.

Also you should not touch ROOT/WEB-INF/lib directory. This is lib dir of LIferay which is different web application than your portlets.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is also possible to have multiple portlets in a single WAR. So if, for some reason, you do not want to add stuff to global libs, you can include all your portlets in a single WAR-file. This way you always have the necessary dependencies available, no matter what Liferay installation is running.